# Is there a way to update and delete a Glip team or group?

Tags: ringcentral, glip

I can retrieve a list of groups/teams or an individual one by using the `chats` API, but I cannot find how to update or delete a group or a team.

The `GET` APIs I use successfully include:

**Get Chat List**

```
GET https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/glip/chats
```

**Get Chat Info by ID**

```
GET https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/glip/chats/{chatId}
```

However, when I try to call `PATCH` or `DELETE` on the Chat ID API endpoint I receive a `404`. Is there a way to delete a Glip team or group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chats` is a new endpoint to cover both Groups and Teams, however `PATCH` and `DELETE` have not been implemented on it yet.

**Update Team**

To update a team, use the old `teams` endpoint. The `teamId` below are the same as the `chatId` provided in the `id` property returned by the "Get Chat List" API.

Only the following body parameters are supported. Use the one(s) you wish to update.

```
PATCH https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/glip/teams/{teamId}

{
  "public": true,
  "name": "My New Team Name",
  "description": "My Fancy Team"
}
```

A successful `PATCH` will return a `200 OK` response with a JSON body of the team properties.

**Delete Team**

To delete a team, use the old `teams` endpoint. The `teamId` below are the same as the `chatId` provided in the `id` property returned by the "Get Chat List" API.

```
DELETE https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/glip/teams/{teamId}
```

A successful response will result in a `204 No Content` response status code.

**Update Group**

There is no option to update a group as it is just a chat with multiple participants.

**Delete Group**

It is not possible to delete a `Group` or a `PrivateChat`. Attempting to do so will result in the error below. To delete a `Group`, convert it to a `Team` first and then delete it.

```
HTTP 400 Bad Request

{
  "errors": [
    {
      "errorCode": "CNV-001",
      "message": "Conversation with type [Group] cannot be deleted."
    }
  ]
}
```